# Add "%" suffix to value displayed inside react-toolbox input number

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

I have a [react-toolbox input component](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/tree/dev/components/input#input) with type "number" as following:

```
<Input
    type="number"
    step="0.01"
    value={itemValue}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this, item)}
/>
```

It displays 2.68

[image]

So, is it possible to display it as 2.68% inside the input field

[image]

Also, the "%" suffix should be kept displayed whenever the value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-toolbox's `<Input />` is a div with a plain `<input>` tag as a child - you could always just use some CSS to get what you want, add the appropriate `className` to your usage of the component.

```css
.rt-input-input {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.rt-input-input::after {
  content: '%';
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rt-input-input">
  <input type="text" value="2.68" />
</div>
```

> Note this won't work on regular `input` tags, as they have no `before/after` pseudo-elements

Comment: As react-toolbox's input component class is `.rt-input-input` ;
by changing `.input` to `.rt-input-input` in proposed solution solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I'm just used to CSS modules where you give zero effs about the actual class name :)